# How to open two view Controllers by pressing same button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am posting this question for the second time, I will make it clear this time as much i can.

I have four `viewControllers` in my `storyboard`, their names are:

**- fView ( has two buttons, one for the user and the other for the provider)**

**- rView ( has one button named "Register" )**

**- gView ( has only background green color )**

**- yView ( has only background yellow color )**

Both, user and provider, will of course go from **fView** to **rView** by pressing everyone's button, but they will be separated when each one press the same button, called here "Register", so user will go to "gView" which has green color, and provider will go to **yView** which has yellow color.

It has been days for now trying to figure it and using if conditions, `prepare(for:sender)`, and `performSegue(withIdentifier identifier:sender)` methods but I final to deadroad.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCHZh.jpg)

Comment: As per your question it looks like u have to put some condition and on the basis of that condition you will have to move to your required view controller.

Comment: Can you add your code in the question, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i have cleared everything in my code sheets since they confused me, i wanna start from beginning one code by one, as i hear the codes will not be out of the code i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have under stood your problems correctly, then you can do what you want the below way,

Take a `boolean` value like **isUser** in your **fView**. Then when you are pressing **user button** in your **fView** make the boolean of **fView** as **true** and when pressing **provider button** make the boolean **false**. Pass it to your **rView** by creating another boolean in **rView**.

Now when user pressing **register button** in **rView** according to the boolean value push the user to the required view controller which are either your **gView** or **yView**. Hope you have understood. For any queries feel free to leave a comment.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Have you done it or is there any problems you're facing?

Comment: but when i embed viewcontrollers in navigationcontrollr it crash :(

Comment: Happy coding. An upvote will be appricated. Thanks. :P